# How to get a jakarta.json.JsonObject Response using the Java 11 HttpClient?

Tags: java, jakarta-jsonp

I want to fetch a **jakarta.json.JsonObject** in the HttpResponse itself using the Jakarta JSONP API. Right now, I have to fetch it as a String, feed the body into a reader and then get the **JsonObject** like the code below.

```
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import jakarta.json.Json;
import jakarta.json.JsonObject;
import jakarta.json.JsonReader;

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(uri).GET().build();
HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.body()));
JsonObject object = jsonReader.readObject();
jsonReader.close();
```

How do I get the response as `HttpResponse<JsonObject> response` directly? **I don't want to use any external libraries other than the Jakarta JSONP one.**

Edit: As an example, one could write their own BodyHandler like this:

```
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodySubscriber;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodySubscribers;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.ResponseInfo;

import jakarta.json.JsonObject;

public class JsonObjectBodyHandler implements HttpResponse.BodyHandler<JsonObject> {

    @Override
    public BodySubscriber<JsonObject> apply(ResponseInfo responseInfo) {
        // How to implement this
    }

}
```

and then use it in the function like this:

```
HttpResponse<JsonObject> response = httpClient.send(request, new JsonObjectBodyHandler());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing JSON using Java 11 HttpClient and custom BodyHandler with Jackson halts and will not proceed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629401/deserializing-json-using-java-11-httpclient-and-custom-bodyhandler-with-jackson)

Comment: @f1sh That doesn't answer the question because it uses Jackson to serialize JSON Response bodies to POJOs and I want to simply convert the body to a JsonObject without any external library.